What software is fit for calculating an atomic and electronic structure of a newly formed nanocluster after injecting impurities into an initial one?
Let's suppose there is a nanocluster and its structrure is known. The problem is to inject impurities into this nanocluster. The impurities can be injected in different quantitites but consist only of two chemical elements. The goal is to obtain atomic and electronic structure of the newly formed material (to naturally be homogeneous). I guess this goal to be more effective reached out by using the machine learning.
What methods and software (free or non-free) are fitted for this purpose?

Related: link, link, link, link.
